# SQL separate one column into three

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically i'm trying to take an address field that is one column and separate it into three columns, the first having the address number, the second having the street name, and the third having if its an apt # or lot #

```
Address
-------------------
990 A street Apt 1B
127 B street Lot 3
```

So far i have this which works for the number and the street.

```
Select LEFT(MP.[ADDRESS],PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', MP.[ADDRESS] )) AS Number,
       LTRIM(RIGHT(MP.[ADDRESS], LEN(MP.[ADDRESS]) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', MP.[ADDRESS] ))) As Street 
From MPFILE mp
```

and it ends up like this:

```
Number  |   Street
----------------------------
990     |    A street Apt 1B
127     |    B Street Lot 3
```

Trying to get this though:

```
Number   |   Street    |  Apt/Lot
-----------------------------------
990      |   A street  |  Apt 1B
127      |   B street  |  Lot 3
```

Comment: is it always an apt or lot # following the street?

Comment: Address rectification is quite complicated, which is why there is special purpose software for it.

Comment: Your street and Apt/Lot calculation will be difficult if the actual street name has more than one word in it.   Example,  `123 Martin Luther King Blvd apt 23-B`

Comment: There isnt always a apt or lot # following the street, no.

Comment: I was trying to see if i could Trim everything before APT and LOT, since those would always be the same, but i haven't had much luck yet with that.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work with your example data given, but as Gordon says Addresses are hard to parse and probably should not be parsed in SQL.

```
WITH locations AS
(
  SELECT ADDRESS, 
          LEN(ADDRESS) AS Len,
          PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', ADDRESS) AS NumLoc,
          PATINDEX('%APT%', ADDRESS) AS APTLoc,
          PATINDEX('%Lot%', ADDRESS) AS LotLoc
  FROM MPFILE
), numbers AS
(
   ADDRESS,
   NumLoc,
   Len - NumLoc AS StartAddr,
   CASE WHEN APTLoc > 0 THEN AptLoc
        WHEN LotLoc > 0 THEN LotLoc
        ELSE Len AS EndAddr,
   CASE WHEN APTLoc > 0 THEN AptLoc
        WHEN LotLoc > 0 THEN LotLoc
        ELSE Len AS StartApt,
   Len AS EndApt
)
Select LEFT(NumLoc, MP.ADDRESS )) AS Number,
       SUBSTRING(MP.ADDRESS, StartAddr, EndAddr), 
       SUBSTRING(MP.ADDRESS, StartApt, EndApt)
From numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @t table  ( Address varchar(200));

Insert Into @t (Address) values
    ('990 A street Apt 1B'),
    ('127 B street Lot 3'),
    ('127 B street Lot 345'),
    ('4444 Rice Street Suite 105'),
    ('715 South King Street #200'),
    ('101 Aupuni Street Room 342')

Select  Left(Address,CHARINDEX(' ',Address)) as Number,
        SUBSTRING(Address,CHARINDEX(' ',Address)+1, CHARINDEX('street',SUBSTRING(Address,CHARINDEX(' ',Address)+1,LEN(Address)))+LEN('street')) as Street
        ,Substring(Address,CHARINDEX('street',Address)+LEN('street'),LEN(Address)) as [Apt/Lot]
From    @t
```

** Result**

```
Number  |Street             |Apt/Lot
----------------------------|-------
990     |A street           |Apt 1B
127     |B street           |Lot 3
127     |B street           |Lot 345
4444    |Rice Street        |Suite 105
715     |South King Street  |#200
101     |Aupuni Street      |Room 342
```